# Postman: How to check whether the field is returning null in the Postman automation

Tags: javascript, api, testing, automated-tests, postman

I have tried with `!== null`, but it is returning PASS even when the field is returning `0` or empty string.

Answer (score 34):

This works as of Mar-2019:

```
pm.test("Check if value is null", function() {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData.<yourField>).not.eq(undefined);
});
```

Comment: `.is.not.undefined` also works. If you really care about null as well, use `is.not.oneOf([null, undefined])`.

Comment: This is the 5th version of this that I've had to look for (no exaggeration). Works for a couple of weeks, then stops. These solutions don't work for me. Neither does .to.eql(null) which is what I had before googling it, which is no longer working for me as of today.

Answer (score 17):

Did you try

```
pm.expect(response.your_field).to.eql(null);
```

?

Comment: OP asked for **Not equal**

Answer (score 12):

If you are checking the Id of the first item returned in a list, you could use `not.equal(null)`:

```
pm.expect(pm.response.json().value[0].Id).not.equal(null);
```

Note that the word "equal" is fully spelled out, although the shortened "eql" does work.

Comment: Not sure if `.to` is redundant, but that is whate I use.

Comment: Good answer, easily checks non null for json element.

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
pm.test("your-value is not null", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.your_value).not.eql(null);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Postman doesn't reference non-existent paths as null, but as undefined.

```
pm.expect(JsonResponse.FAKE.PATH).not.eql(undefined);
```

This test should fail, as this fake json path is actually undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. But checking it in following way worked for me

```
tests["Item is not null"] = 
    jsonData.item !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access response json like :

```
    var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    var yourVAr = json.yourVar
    if(yourVar == null){
        //your var is null here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar, this is one part of the code and its works well
Check this code

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for(i=0; i<jsonData.data.length; i++){
tests["due date is between given date range"] = jsonData.data[i].duedate < environment.Cenddate && jsonData.data[i].duedate > environment.Cstartdate;

tests["response body has department name"] = jsonData.data[i].department.name !== null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["Item is not null"] = 
    jsonData.item !== null && 
    jsonData.item !== ' ' && 
    jsonData.item !== 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta place the + [i] after the function you gonna validate on the tests[] so only it will return valid statements on each array. For example,

```
function checkIsNull() {
    var items = json.data.pois.items
    var PlaceIdIsNull = true;
    var subTypeExtraIsNull = true;
    var websiteIsNull = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].placeId !== null) {
        PlaceIdIsNull = false;
    }
    if (items[i].subTypeExtra !== null) {
        subTypeExtraIsNull = false;
    }
    if (items[i].website === null) {
        websiteIsNull = false;
        tests['website is null only happened on these arrays' + [i]] = true;
        }
        tests['Place ID is null '] = PlaceIdIsNull
        tests['subTypeExtra is null '] = subTypeExtraIsNull
}
}
       checkIsNull();
```

## Result:

---

### PASS   Place ID is null

### PASS   subTypeExtra is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.expect(jsonData["yourfield"]).to.eq(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as at Sept.19, 2022

```
     pm.test("Check that response body is not null", ()=>{
   pm.response.to.be.have.body
    })
```