# Check null value in Postman test cases .not.eql() or .not.equal() are not working

Tags: postman, chai, postman-testcase

I'm working with a API project and using Postman for testing APIs. I wrote few test cases to check null as follows,

```
//user id is present
pm.test("user id is present", function() {
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].userId).not.eql(null);
});
```

Also tried with `.not.equal()` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121154/4753489) answer.

```
//user id is present
pm.test("user id is present", function() {
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].userId).not.equal(null);
});
```

However, this all are getting passed even if the userId is `null`. Any furhter thought to check null value in Postman test case?

Comment: `.to.not.be.null`? https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_null But it always says in the docs that this is not recommend...

Comment: @DannyDainton: Tried `.to.not.be.null` however, no luck so far. Yes, I checked doc already, but then what is alternative?

Comment: Just trying to find something locally that works. Seems like nothing I've tried (each example I've come across) gives me the result I want. :( This feels like it should be so difficult...but it's proving to be. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, open the console and run the flowing snippet to check the types:

```
pm.test("user id is present", function() {
   console.log(typeof jsonData.data[0].userId);
   console.log(typeof jsonData.data[0]);
   console.log(typeof jsonData);
}
```

If you get `undefined` for `jsonData.data[0].userId`, you need change your test to assert `null` and `undefined`:

```
pm.test("user id is present", function() {
   pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].userId).to.exist //check if it is not equal to undefined
   pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].userId).to.not.be.null; //if it is not equal to null
}
```

Comment: Very odd this problem, I made some tests in my postman and worked fine. My version is 6.7.2

Comment: Did you parse your JSON data with JSON.parse?

Comment: using `pm.response.json();`

Comment: Try this: pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].userId).to.satisfy(function (userId) {
        if (userId === null) {
            return false;
        } else { return true }
    });

Comment: Thanks Ângelo, I will surly try this and let you know, see you tomorrow!

Comment: Can you run this snippet and send the result to me? console.log(typeof jsonData.data[0].userId); console.log(typeof jsonData.data[0]); console.log(typeof jsonData);

Comment: `undefined`, `object`, `object`

Comment: Okay, so I have to check with `undefined` instead of null i.e `.not.eql(undefined)`

Comment: Exactly! I will change the answer and add all the main points of this discussion.