# How to sanitize a [null] array input for my API program?

Tags: php, postman

I am calling API through postman and passing following parameters.

```
reason: string
staff_ids[]:
```

When pass `staff_ids` blank then I got `[null]` in server-side.

so that the condition gets always true.

```
if(isset($request->staff_ids) && !empty($request->staff_ids)){
//
}
```

Is there any way to check if array has `[null]`?

Comment: `isset($request->staff_ids['null'])`?

Comment: I think this will be a specific condition. I am looking to check array if it has some return otherwise false.

Comment: `if (is_array($request->staff_ids) && count($request->staff_ids) == 0) { echo 'I am empty'; }`

Comment: Actually I think I misinterpreted your question and perhaps it should be `implode(',', $request->staff_ids) == 'null'`

Comment: What is `I got [null] in server-side` - array('null'),  array(), array(NULL) ?

Comment: @splash58, getting a response as a: `[null]` in postman.

Comment: Maybe, help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993222/postman-how-to-check-whether-the-field-is-returning-null-in-the-postman-automat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking, you may simply filter out all `NULL` values before other works

```php
if (!isset($request->staff_ids) || $request->staff_ids === null) {
  $request->staff_ids = array(); // default to empty array if is not set or is null
} 

if (!empty($request->staff_ids)) {
  $request->staff_ids = array_filter($request->staff_ids, function ($id) {
    return ($id !== null);
  });

  if (!empty($request->staff_ids)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: when uncheck staff_ids[] field in postman it gives `array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: So `$request->staff_ids` might not be set at all. In that case, I've updated my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, exactly your solution working for me Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have filtered array values before checking as **@KoalaYeung** Answered. It is working fine.

```
$request->staff_ids = array_filter($request->staff_ids, function ($id) {
        return ($id !== null);
      });

    if(isset($request->staff_ids) && !empty($request->staff_ids)){
      ///

    }
```

Is there any better approach?

Comment: It depends on which level are you planning to fix. Do you want Postman to not send that `[NULL]` array in the first place? Or do you think is your server side script that generates the `[NULL]` array? Or do you simply want to sanitize your input?

Comment: You' re not showing enough of your code to allow deeper diagnosis.

Comment: Simply I want to sanitize your input.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this with is_null function and sizeof() for array

```
if(!is_null($request->staff_ids) && sizeof($request->staff_ids)){
}
```